# Get the key corresponding to the minimum value from the following dictionary

Tags: dictionary, key, minimum

Having the following Dictionary :
sampleDict = {
'Sami': 82,
'Ali': 65,
'Muna': 75
}

Get the key corresponding to the minimum value from the following dictionary

Comment: in python please

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```py
sampleDict = { 'Sami': 82, 'Ali': 65, 'Muna': 75, 'Kanaan': 65 }
min_value = min(sampleDict.values())
min_keys = [key for key, value in sampleDict.items() if value == min_value]
print(min_keys)
# prints ['Ali', 'Kanaan']
```

Keep in mind that there might be multiple keys having the minimum value

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {
  'Physics': 82,
  'Math': 65,
  'history': 75,
  'PE': 65
}
print(min(dictionary, key=dictionary.get))
```

This example would back only first element with min value, looking very clean if somebody needs this :)